# How to initiate Controller of one service (MVC project) to other service in ASP .NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I have two service in my project one is **Events** service and other is **Parky** service (both are in different sln file and both have their own Controllers). I can only run controllers of one service at a time. Example when I build Parky service, I can't call any of method in Event Controllers.

What changes should I do in Startup.cs of **Parky** service such that when I run **Parky** Service, All **Event** Service's Controller method is callable?

I am using ASP .NET Core (MVC).
[image: File Structure]

[image: Parky Service Startup File]

Comment: You would not make changes in startup to do this.  If you wish to use a controller and its an api controller then call it using httpclient.

Comment: Yes, you can't just put your Event service controller inside your Parky service. You have 2 options:
1) Create client for event service and use it in parky service
2) Share your logic and repositories between 2 projects and call repositories from Parky service.